# Flutter-Web: Mouse hover -> Change cursor to pointer

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How can the cursor appearance be changed within Flutter?
I know that with the [Listener()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html) Widget we can listen for Mouse-Events,
but I haven't found any information regarding hovering events for flutter web.

Has someone found a soulution yet?

Comment: SO is Q&A site, we don not include answers in question posts. If you wish, then post an answer

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I had difficulties finding documentation on the now built-in support. Here is what helped me: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58260

And this did the trick for me, without changing index.html etc.

```
MouseRegion(
  cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
    child: GestureDetector(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add_comment,
        size: 20,
        ),
      onTap: () {},
    ),
  ),
```

Also see the official documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MouseCursor-class.html

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: MouseRegion(
      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.text,
      child: Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

And here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateMouseCursor-class.html yet another wonderful example from the official docs that "...defines a mouse cursor that resolves to SystemMouseCursors.forbidden when its widget is disabled."

Comment: Things are changing fast with Flutter. A few weeks ago [Khari Lane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58847985/3291390) worked but I couldn't get it to now. This works great and does not require a bunch of custom code or changing index.html.

Comment: In 2021, looks like this is done automatically with a 1.22 updates to buttons

Comment: This import is also needed
`import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';`

Comment: how about for `DropdownButton` its not work for this .

Answer (score 20):

Starting with **dev** channel build version 1.19.0–3.0.pre there is built-in support for the pointer cursor. The same method as bellow is used with the difference that is applied to the Flutter app container element `flt-glass-pane`. Using the bellow method will just duplicate the behavior.

In order to override the `pointer` cursor, you can use the bellow method but applied on the `flt-glass-pane` element.

A workaround for this is the following:

1. You have to set an **id** (for example **app-container** on the entire **body** of the app's **index.html** template).

This is how your **index.html** will look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My awesome app</title>
</head>
<body id="app-container">
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Next, you have to create a wrapper dart class. I called it **hand_cursor.dart**:

```
import 'package:flutter_web/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web/widgets.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
// see https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html

class HandCursor extends MouseRegion {

  // get a reference to the body element that we previously altered 
  static final appContainer = html.window.document.getElementById('app-container');

  HandCursor({Widget child}) : super(
    onHover: (PointerHoverEvent evt) {
      appContainer.style.cursor='pointer';
      // you can use any of these: 
      // 'help', 'wait', 'move', 'crosshair', 'text' or 'pointer'
      // more options/details here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/stylesc.htm
    },
    onExit: (PointerExitEvent evt) {
      // set cursor's style 'default' to return it to the original state
      appContainer.style.cursor='default';
    },
    child: child
  );

}
```

3. After that, wherever you want to have the hand cursor shown, you have to wrap your element in this HandCursor wrapper. See the class **awesome_button.dart** bellow:

```
import 'package:awesome_app/widgets/containers/hand_cursor.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web/widgets.dart';

class AwesomeButton extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        HandCursor(
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // do some magic
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.star)
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

A short explanation can be found [here](https://medium.com/@constanting/handcursor-for-flutter-web-6552bed19f91).

A more versatile update, that works on the new web projects created with the **master** channel of Flutter, can be found [here](https://medium.com/@constanting/customcursor-for-flutter-b6f252c0dcbb).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this answe, it seems legit. I will try it out when I have time to and will come back here.

Answer (score 14):

You can use an InkWell that has an onHover event

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    onHover: (value) {
      setState(() {
        isHovered = value;
      });
    },
    child: Container(
      width: 50,
      height: 72,
      color: Colors.black   
    )
);
```

Make sure to have something onTap, even an empty function, else it is considered to be disabled, and the hover won't work

Answer (score 9):

The previous method is deprecated. Here is the updated code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_sdk/html.dart' as html;

class HandCursor extends MouseRegion {
  static final appContainer = html.window.document.getElementById('app-container');
  HandCursor({Widget child})
      : super(
          onHover: (PointerHoverEvent evt) {
            appContainer.style.cursor = 'pointer';
          },
          onExit: (PointerExitEvent evt) {
            appContainer.style.cursor = 'default';
          },
          child: child,
        );
}
```

And in your pubspec.yaml file, add universal_html as a package as a dependency. The version may change.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  universal_html: ^1.1.4
```

You still want to have an id of app-container attached to the body of your html. Here is my html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Your App Title</title>
</head>
<body id="app-container">
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You want to put the code for the HandCursor widget in its own file. You can call it hand_cursor.dart. And to use it on the widget you want the hand to show up on, import it into the file you're working on and wrap the widget you want in the HandCursor widget.

Answer (score 8):

The most easy way what i know

```
InkWell(
        onTap: (){},
        mouseCursor: MaterialStateMouseCursor.clickable,
        ...
```

Answer (score 7):

From Flutter beta version `1.19.0-4.1.pre`, add id to `body` and set cursor of that doesn't work. Because `flt-glass-pane` is replacing the cursor.
So the solution is that set cursor directly to `flt-glass-pane`.

Below is the update that is working.

```
class HandCursor extends MouseRegion {
    static final appContainer = html.window.document.querySelectorAll('flt-glass-pane')[0];
    HandCursor({Widget child}) : super(
        onHover: (PointerHoverEvent evt) {
            appContainer.style.cursor='pointer';
        },
        onExit: (PointerExitEvent evt) {
            appContainer.style.cursor='default';
        },
        child: child
    );    
}
```

Comment: Been looking for this for quite a while, thanks for that!!

Answer (score 5):

```
final appContainer 
     = html.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] as html.Element;

            GestureDetector(
                        child: MouseRegion(
                          child: Text(
                            'https://github.com/yumi0629',
                            style: textStyle,
                          ),
                          onHover: (_) => appContainer.style.cursor = 'pointer',
                          onExit: (_) => appContainer.style.cursor = 'default',
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          print('open');
                          js.context.callMethod(
                              'open', ['https://github.com/yumi0629']);
                        },
                      )
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe that mouse events won't work on the web, Listener Widget was demoed on Google I/O 2019 and worked with mouse, but that was as a ChromeOS app and not a web app.

According to [Flutter web on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web):

> At this time, desktop UI interactions are not fully complete, so a UI built with flutter_web may feel like a mobile app, even when running on a desktop browser.

Comment: Thank you, I was indeed thinking I missed something because they had something working at I/O

Answer (score 2):

**Adapted answer by Constantin Stan**

For those who want to have the click effect similar to `InkWell` widget and with border radius option:

Add to your pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  universal_html: ^1.1.4
```

Then add to the index.html file the following the tag `<body id="app-container">` as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Your App Title</title>
</head>
<body id="app-container">
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally create the following widget and use encapsulated all the necessary widgets:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_sdk/html.dart' as html;

class InkWellMouseRegion extends InkWell {
  InkWellMouseRegion({
    Key key,
    @required Widget child,
    @required GestureTapCallback onTap,
    double borderRadius = 0,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          child: !kIsWeb ? child : HoverAware(child: child),
          onTap: onTap,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
        );
}

class HoverAware extends MouseRegion {

  // get a reference to the body element that we previously altered 
  static final appContainer = html.window.document.getElementById('app-container');

  HoverAware({Widget child}) : super(
    onHover: (PointerHoverEvent evt) {
      appContainer.style.cursor='pointer';
      // you can use any of these: 
      // 'help', 'wait', 'move', 'crosshair', 'text' or 'pointer'
      // more options/details here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/stylesc.htm
    },
    onExit: (PointerExitEvent evt) {
      // set cursor's style 'default' to return it to the original state
      appContainer.style.cursor='default';
    },
    child: child
  );

}
```

Comment: If you app is web only , you don't need to depend on "universal_html" package , just  'import 'dart:html' as html' will work.